# analysis of randomized bst

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am reading about Randomized Binary search trees in Algorithms in C++  by Robert Segdewick.

There is still a chance that the random number generator could lead to the wrong decision at every opportunity, and thus leave us with poorly balanced trees, but we can analyze this chance mathematically and prove it to be vanishingly small.

Property 13.2. : The probability that the construction cost of a randomized BST is more than a factor of α times the average is less than e–α

For example, it takes about 2.3 million comparisons to build a randomized BST of 100,000 nodes, but the probability that the number of comparisons will be more than 23 million is much less than 0.01 percent. Such a performance guarantee is more than adequate for meeting the practical requirements of processing real data sets of this size. When using a standard BST for such a task, we cannot provide such a guarantee: for example, we are subject to performance problems if there is significant order in the data, which is unlikely in random data, but certainly would not be unusual in real data, for a host of reasons.

A result analogous to Property 13.2 also holds for the running time of quicksort, by the same argument. But the result is more important here, because it also implies that the cost of searching in the tree is close to the average. Regardless of any extra costs in constructing the trees, we can use the standard BST implementation to perform search operations, with costs that depend only on the shape of the trees, and no extra costs at all for balancing. This property is important in typical applications, where search operations are far more numerous than are any others. For example, the 100,000-node BST described in the previous paragraph might hold a telephone directory, and might be used for millions of searches. We can be nearly certain that each search will be within a small constant factor of the average cost of about 23 comparisons, and, for practical purposes, we do not have to worry about the possibility that a large number of searches would cost close to 100,000 comparisons, whereas with standard BSTs, we would need to be concerned.

My question on above text is

1. What does author mean by " We can be nearly certain that each search will be within a small constant factor of the average cost of about 23 comparisons, and, for practical purposes". Here what is small constant factor.

Thanks

Comment: In the first big par. you say 2.3 million and then 23 million. Is that correct or a typo?

Comment: I think it's correct and it also makes sense together with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already mention quicksort, which is a perfect example of such algorithm. Quicksort has a nasty worst case performance of `O(N^2)`. However, it's one of the most widely used sorting algorithms all over.

Why are such algorithms used? **Because the worst case is really rare. So rare that it's worth using the algorithm even if it occurs once or twice.** It could be much easier to implement than the guaranteed solution, it could cooperate better with the contemporary hardware (caches) etc.

It's usually better to use quicksort instead of heapsort, even though heapsort is better in theory (consumes `O(1)` extra memory and `O(N log N)` time in worst case).

So, in my opinion, the book wants to say that randomized BST are worth using even if things can go south. Simply because the probability of such case is really, really low. It's not a good idea to use such structure in a crucial part of a real time system. However, for an average application, using a randomized structure might be helpful. Because the probability of being as good as self-balancing tree is quite high. Because you save a lot of time not coding the self balancing. CPU time is cheap, developer's time is expensive.

Personally, I use randomized approach when coding union-find. For the guaranteed worst case complexity, you should join a smaller set to the larger one, I do this randomly. It saves a few lines, some memory and I haven't noticed a difference between the randomized and the guaranteed version in practice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, the above holds for *random* data. But for quicksort, it's mostly about the pivot selection, which usually isn't randomized and uses `k` fixed positions in the array. If it was randomized too, such attack would be hardly possible.

Comment: you're right, my comment makes no sense :) Deleting it

Answer (score 0):

So the probability distribution will be a binomial distribution, which for large numbers is approximately normal with some mean and variance. So his proposition is conceptually equivalent to [Chebyshev's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Statement).

Essentially, its saying that the tails of the distribution are smaller than some amount, and most of the distribution is within some distance of the center.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a specific bound. Fix `j` and `n` such that `1 <= j <= n`. Imagine a random BST on element 1..n and, for all `k >= 0`, let `T(k)` be the size of the subtree rooted at that ancestor of `j` having depth `k` (or `0` if `j` has depth less than `k`). Then,

```
T(0) = n
E[T(k) | T(k - 1)] <= (3/4) T(k - 1),
```

by the following logic. Let `m = T(k - 1)` and assume that `m > 0`. Choose a subtree root uniformly of rank `i` among `m` possibilities. In the worst case, `j` lies in the larger subtree, so `T(k) <= max(i - 1, m - 1 - i)`. Computing an expectation,

```
E[T(k) | m] <= sum_{i : 1 <= i <= m} max(i - 1, m - 1 - i)/m
             = sum_{i : 1 <= i <= m - floor(m/2) - 1} (m - 1 - i)/m
                 + [m even] ((m - 1)/2)/m
                 + sum_{i : floor(m/2) + 1 <= i <= m} (i - 1)/m
             = sum_{i : floor(m/2) + 1 <= i <= m} 2 (i - 1)/m
                 + [m even] (m - 1)/(2 m)
             = floor(m/2) (floor(m/2) + m - 1)/m
                 + [m even] (m - 1)/(2 m).
```

If `m` is even, then the bound is

```
(m/2) (m/2 + m - 1)/m + (m - 1)/(2 m) = (3 m/2 - 1)/2 + 1/2 - 1/(2 m)
                                      < (3/4) m.
```

If `m` is odd, then the bound is

```
((m - 1)/2) ((m - 1)/2 + m - 1)/m < (m/2) (m/2 + m)/m = (3/4) m.
```

---

Now, by the linearity of expectation, we compute

```
E[T(k)] <= (3/4)^k n.
```

The binary search is active after `k` comparisons if and only if `T(k) >= 1`. It's clear that

```
Pr(T(k) >= 1) <= E[T(k)],
```

which, in a more general form, is known as Markov's inequality. If we set `k = 3 log_{4/3} n ~ 7.23 lg n = O(log n)`, then the probability that a search is still active is at most `(3/4)^k = n^-3`. Union bound over all elements, and the probability that *some* element is too deep is at most `n^-2`. By the time `n = 1e5`, this is already better than one in a billion.